# How can Engineering Equation Solver solve both equations and a table?

Tags: software

I don't know why they tried to ruin EES by doing this, but what people want to do is have the solver recognize an equation with a variable, and then take that same variable and plot a table of it with varying values in a separate parametric table.

The problem is it the software states a conflict between assuming two definitions of the variable at once, so unlike competently designed software, users have to choose between either a table or the equation solver, not both. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Please explain how one variable can have two different values at the same time.

Comment: Haven't used EES in a few years, but I recall there is something like `$IFNOTTABLE:` which allows you to use a default value if there isn't a table value available. I likely got the syntax wrong, but you should be able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an MWE showing what you're doing, so we can check whether there's a mistake in your implementation or understanding of EES. I'd also suggest reformulating your question to sound like less of a rant.